# 'How do I stop this message? "This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because this Linux system will no longer be supported"

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome 48.0

I receive this message every time I start "Chrome" How do I turn the message of, short of closing it every time? I do want to switch browsers, just not see the notice.

```
This computer will soon stop receiving Google Chrome updates because this Linux system will no longer be supported
```

Comment: What Linux OS? What version? Where did you install Chrome from?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome was from Google..  They are going to stop supporting it, I just want the message to go away.